# Keep only text between Lesser than and Greater than

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

```
with src as (
   select 'hello <blah1> boy and <blah2>' as int from dual
)
select regexp_replace(int, '\<(.+?)\>')
from src;
```

Hello, how can I keep only **blah1** and **blah2** - the opposite of what the query is returning right now.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below when there are more than 2 tags as blah

```
        WITH src
         AS (SELECT '<ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82> at scbus0 target 6 lun 0 (pass0,da0), <ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82> at scbus0 target 7 lun 0 (pass1,da1), <ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82> at scbus0 target 8 lun 0 (pass2,da2), <ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82> at scbus0 target 9 lun 0 (pass3,da3), <DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64> at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (pass4,ada0), <DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64> at scbus2 target 0 lun 0 (pass5,ada1),
     ' AS INT
             FROM   dual),
         lvltab
         AS (SELECT LEVEL lvl
             FROM   dual,
                    src
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Regexp_count(INT, '\<(.+?)\>'))
    SELECT TRANSLATE(Listagg(Regexp_substr (INT, '\<(.+?)\>', 1, lvl), ', ')
                       within GROUP ( ORDER BY INT), 'a<>', 'a')
    FROM   src,
           lvltab
```

In case there are multiple rows you can use the below

```
        WITH src
         AS (SELECT 'hello <blah1> boy and <blah2>' AS INT
             FROM   dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'hello <blah1> boy and <blah2>' AS INT
             FROM   dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'hello <blah1> boy and <blah2> <black> <sheep>' AS INT
             FROM   dual),
         src1
         AS (SELECT INT
                    ||ROWNUM AS INT
             FROM   src),
         lvltab
         AS (SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL lvl
             FROM   dual,
                    src1
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Regexp_count(INT, '\<(.+?)\>')
             ORDER  BY lvl DESC)
    SELECT req
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Listagg(Regexp_substr (a.INT, '\<(.+?)\>', 1, lvl), ' ')
                              within GROUP ( ORDER BY a.INT, lvl) over (
                                PARTITION BY a.INT) req,
                            a.INT
            FROM   lvltab b,
                   src1 a
            ORDER  BY a.INT);
```

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't much clearer in my question. In fact, the real field's value looks like: 
**<ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>** at scbus0 target 6 lun 0 (pass0,da0), **<ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>** at scbus0 target 7 lun 0 (pass1,da1), **<ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>** at scbus0 target 8 lun 0 (pass2,da2), **<ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>** at scbus0 target 9 lun 0 (pass3,da3), **<DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64>** at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (pass4,ada0), **<DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64>** at scbus2 target 0 lun 0 (pass5,ada1),

Comment: - so the number of HDDs is variable, I need to keep only the text between '<' and '>' for each occurrence, in a single statement if possible. In fact, the question is how can we remove everything outside the delimiters ? The result will be: `ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82, ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82, ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82, ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82, DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64, DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64`    - all in one line. Thank you very much.

Comment: i have modified the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as follows:

```
SQL> with src as (
  2     select 'hello <blah1> boy and <blah2>' as int from dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT
  5      REGEXP_SUBSTR(INT, '\<(.+?)\>', 1, 1)
  6      || ' '
  7      || REGEXP_SUBSTR(INT, '\<(.+?)\>', 1, 2) AS RESULT
  8  FROM
  9      SRC;

RESULT
---------------
<blah1> <blah2>

SQL>
```

The second last parameter in `REGEXP_SUBSTR` indicates the starting position to start the search and the last parameter in `REGEXP_SUBSTR` indicates the occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I was searching for:

**REGEXP_REPLACE(INT, '.*?(\<(.+?)>|$)', '\1, ' )**

The result is:

```
<ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>, <ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>, <ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>, <ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N 0A82>, <DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64>, <DOGFISH SSD 64GB V8301c64>, , ,
```

I need only to remove the <, > and I'm good. Thanks.